Need to make a Query in Google Sheets from a multiple dropdown list into a cell containing coma separated values
I've got a Google Sheet with data (Columns A,B,C), a dropdown list (E) and source for this dropdown list (G)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XY5Nfwi-DtXIV7PMkhax_60EpX5puawmUF-fl2qvEqk/edit?usp=sharing
I use an Apps Script to allow multiple selection on this dropdown and separated by a coma (,).
I need to make a QUERY to get All line where at least one of value in selected value from dropdown list is containing by one or more users.
Ex. If I choose A, B ... Jean, Patrick and Fabrice will be shown as result !
It's a Query with OR not AND (after I'll had a way to choose between 'Or' and 'And'
I know how to make a query from a value in a dropdown list ... but if more than one value is selected I don't know how to do this

I’m voting to close this question because the premise of using a data validation dropdown in Google Sheets to select more than one value is impossible. P.D. The linked spreadsheet shows an error for the current value of  E2, A, B, C, D, E

You can try this
=let(z;iferror(tocol(map(SPLIT(E2;", ");lambda(k;".*"&k&".*"))));query(A:C;"select B where C matches '"&textjoin("|";1;z)&"' "))

I used let, map, and split to create an array of partial match wildcards (using .* syntax) from the E2 dropdown. In the query, I used the match syntax against the array.

Use CONTAINS in your Query
From your example, you may manually use:
=QUERY(A1:C5,"Select A,B,C where C contains 'A' OR C contains 'B'")

Which results to:

However, if you want to make it dynamic, you can use:
=QUERY(A1:C5,"Select A,B,C where C contains '"&JOIN("' OR C CONTAINS '",SPLIT(E2,","))&"'")

which builds your query by replacing the commas in your input into OR C CONTAINS  to get:

If you want to just list the names (or the data on column B), you can use:
=JOIN(", ",QUERY(A1:C5,"Select B where C contains '"&JOIN("' OR C CONTAINS '",SPLIT(E2,","))&"'"))

to get:

References:

Query Function
Query Language
Split Function
Join Function


Please feel free to ask anything with respect to the answer posted above.
